# Register always gives me default error

Tags: php, pdo

I'm making a login and register system, using PDO for the database connection. When I wanna check the username it returns the default error:

```
Sorry, that username is already taken. Please choose another one.
```

even when I'm just typing `hduigifugfulgfrfg` it ALWAYS gives me that error :/

My code:

```
 } else if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_email=:user_email');
        $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_check_user_name->execute();
        $result = $query_check_user_name->fetchAll();
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
                $this->errors[] = ($result[$i]['user_name'] == $user_name) ? MESSAGE_USERNAME_EXISTS : MESSAGE_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS;
            }
```

Does anyone see a mistake or something? I'm looking for one so long that I don't see anything anymore :P

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for the following statement?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    //Do Something
}
```

Try replacing your code with this:

```
 } else if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
    $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_email=:user_email');
    $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query_check_user_name->execute();
    $result = $query_check_user_name->fetchAll();
    if (count($result) > 0) {
       $this->errors[] = ($result[$i]['user_name'] == $user_name) ? MESSAGE_USERNAME_EXISTS : MESSAGE_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS;
        }
```

The rest of the code looks perfectly fine, it's saying Count how many rows have the same username or email. If it is over greater then `0` output an error. That seems perfectly fine, except the `for` statement.